# How to construct a dict from lists or numpy arrays?

Tags: python

Can you please teach me to construct a dict from lists?

I have two lists:

```
A = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
```

and

```
B = ['HAM', 'SPAM', 'HAM', 'HAM', 'SPAM']
```

I want a dict like this:

```
Dict = [
...     {'Count': 1., 'Class': 'HAM'},
...     {'Count': 2., 'Class': 'SPAM'},
...     {'Count': 0., 'Class': 'HAM'},
...     {'Count': 0., 'Class': 'HAM'},
...     {'Count': 3., 'Class': 'SPAM'},
... ]
```

Which include two feature keys 'Count' and 'Class' as well...

Much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: That's not a dictionary, that's a list of dictionaries. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a dict, but a list (of dictionaries). Anyway, if what you want is this:

```
data = [
            {'Count': 1., 'Class': 'HAM'},
            {'Count': 2., 'Class': 'SPAM'},
            {'Count': 0., 'Class': 'HAM'},
            {'Count': 0., 'Class': 'HAM'},
            {'Count': 3., 'Class': 'SPAM'}
       ]
```

then:

```
data = [{'Count': float(x[0]), 'Class': x[1]} for x in zip(A, B)]
```

**update**

I've updated my answer because I've just noticed that you required a float as value for 'Count'.

Comment: That's basically a copy-paste of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your answer before mine. I can delete mine for honesty if you want, but it wasn't a copy-paste, just the same.

Comment: Meh it's fine to leave it up, it show's that there's a consensus :) great minds think alike

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
>>> B = ['HAM', 'SPAM', 'HAM', 'HAM', 'SPAM']

>>> zip(A,B)
[(1, 'HAM'), (2, 'SPAM'), (0, 'HAM'), (0, 'HAM'), (3, 'SPAM')]

>>> [{'Count':i[0], 'Class':i[1]} for i in zip(A,B)]
```

Output

```
[{'Count': 1, 'Class': 'HAM'},
 {'Count': 2, 'Class': 'SPAM'},
 {'Count': 0, 'Class': 'HAM'},
 {'Count': 0, 'Class': 'HAM'},
 {'Count': 3, 'Class': 'SPAM'}]
```

Comment: Instead of using an index why not just unpack the values?   for key,value in zip(A,B)

Answer (score 1):

The `Dict = [{}, {}, ...]` construct you have there is not a dict but a list (`[]`) of dicts (`{}`).

To get the required result using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3]
>>> B = ['HAM', 'SPAM', 'HAM', 'HAM', 'SPAM']

>>> [{'Count': a, 'Class': b} for a, b in zip(A, B)]
[{'Count': 1, 'Class': 'HAM'},
 {'Count': 2, 'Class': 'SPAM'},
 {'Count': 0, 'Class': 'HAM'},
 {'Count': 0, 'Class': 'HAM'},
 {'Count': 3, 'Class': 'SPAM'}]
```

Comment: Values of the `Count` key should be numbers.

Comment: @f_ficarola You are right, got confused by the `.` and the syntax coloring. Fixed, almost the same as others now. Still laving it here for the `zip` expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a list of dicts (i.e. records), you can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

`pandas` is perfect for representing this kind of data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Count': A, 'Class': B})
df
=> 
  Class  Count
0   HAM      1
1  SPAM      2
2   HAM      0
3   HAM      0
4  SPAM      3

[5 rows x 2 columns]

df.Class
=>
0     HAM
1    SPAM
2     HAM
3     HAM
4    SPAM
Name: Class, dtype: object

df.Class[1]
=> 'SPAM'

df.ix[1]
=>
Class    SPAM
Count       2
Name: 1, dtype: object

df.ix[1].Class
=> 'SPAM'
```